# VBA for Mac - msoFileDialogFolderPicker is not defined?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

when I tried to run it, it showed error with the msoFileDIalogFolderPicker not defined. I already checked reference to Office 14 library but still didnt work?

```
Dim MyFolder As String 'Path collected from the folder picker dialog
Dim MyFile As String 
Dim wbk As Workbook 
On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a Mac, but with reference of (https://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac017.htm), try the below (you may need to tweak it in places) and see if it does what you need it to:

```
Sub Select_Folder_On_Mac()
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim RootFolder As String
    Dim scriptstr As String

    On Error Resume Next
    RootFolder = MacScript("return (path to desktop folder) as String")
    'Or use RootFolder = "Macintosh HD:Users:YourUserName:Desktop:TestMap:"
    'Note : for a fixed path use : as seperator in 2011 and 2016

    If Val(Application.Version) < 15 Then
        scriptstr = "(choose folder with prompt ""Select the folder""" & _
            " default location alias """ & RootFolder & """) as string"
    Else
        scriptstr = "return posix path of (choose folder with prompt ""Select the folder""" & _
            " default location alias """ & RootFolder & """) as string"
    End If

    folderPath = MacScript(scriptstr)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If folderPath <> "" Then
        MsgBox folderPath
    End If
End Sub
```